# Is it possible to display all files in a server on my Android app?

Tags: android, list, directory, webserver

I have already created an android app and set up a http server as well. Presently I'm using webview in my app along with a server side php script to display the files in my server. But it gets slow and the UI isn't very good. Is there an android code which I can use to display the files on my app activity with a download option ?

Answer (score 0):

Doing in directly from android will be even slower. Why don't you just enable directory view for that folder on your web server and display the directory page. You will automatically get download links.

Comment: That is what I'm doing now. I have a server side directory lister php and I use webview on my activity. Thank you!

Comment: Well then that is the fastest I must say :) To make it more efficient you could write a custom page showing paginated view of the files, if your file list is very large.

Comment: `That is what I'm doing now.` Don't think so if you use your own php script for that. What was ment was that your webserver is enabled to deliver directory listings. Has nothing to do with php. The webserver itself will generate the listings.

Comment: Yes I know that, but the php script gives a better user interface.